# what is wrong with this code it shows sigtstp Runtime error in codechef compiler

Tags: c++

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;


int main(){
    int T,N;

    cin>>T;
    while(T--){
        cin>>N;
        int arr[N];
        for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
            cin>>arr[i];
        }
    sort(arr, arr+N);
    int x=arr[0];

    int y=arr[N/2];
    int z=arr[N-1];
    int a=((abs(x-y)+abs(y-z)+abs(z-x)));
    cout<<a<<endl;
    }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's wrong? The unholy trinity of competetive programming: [`using namespace std;`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) [`#include<bits/stdc++.h>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h) and [VLAs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard) ;)

Comment: Variable-length arrays are not part of the C++ standard, and are very likely to cause stack overflows. Use `std::vector<int>`.

Comment: Use `std::vector` instead of an array, and see if that helps

Comment: https://www.codechef.com/FEB21C/problems/MAXFUN question link

Comment: Replace `int arr[N];` with `std::vector<int> arr(n);` and give a try. VLA could be causing issue here

Comment: The result can be as large as 4. 10^9 (with negative input values). Too large for an `int`. Besides, I don't think you need to sort the array. You only need the min and max. This implies that you don't need any array.

Comment: You can use dynamic allocation and see if that helps https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/9zM8Yh

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, you should avoid:

- #include<bits/stdc++.h>
- using namespace std;
- VLA

However, as this kind of site unfortunately promotes this way of writing C++ code, and as N = 10^5 is not so large, it is unlikely that these are the reasons of the run time error.

In practice, the result is equal to `2*(max - min)`. As the absolute values are less or equal to 10^9, this implies that the result can be as large as 4 10^9 (assuming negative and positive inputs). This is too large for an `int`.

Moreover, sorting is useless here. You can just calculate the min and max values when reading the `A` values.

Another consequence is that you don't need any array, and therefore any VLA!

Comment: Note: I submitted a code (just to check this answer) and I got a correct 100% validation, with a time of 0.02s, for a time limit of 1s.